# Mention chat in the FAQ

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, help-center

From the FAQs for all sites, under "What kinds of questions should I *not* ask here?":

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate 
>   in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.

Now that we have a "third place" where discussions are okay, shouldn't it be mentioned in the FAQ?

Comment: Great idea! We've been pointing people to chat in comments on Programmers. Would be nice to have a FAQ note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great idea! I just added this to the faq like so:

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, you are more than welcome to have such discussions in our [real time web chat](http://example.com).
>
> If your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK.